# Unable to extend HTMLElement onclick for a custom element from its class method

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have been working on a custom element where I want to extend the default onclick behavior for it. While it work if I add it to the element itself, it does not work when defining the function within the class. I thought it would work, I understand most javascript scoping concepts but I don't seem to grasp this one and haven't been able to find information on this specific case. What concept am I missing?

I found this reference, but I don't think it apply. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

> Note that classes cannot extend regular (non-constructible) objects. If you want to inherit from a regular object, you can instead use Object.setPrototypeOf():

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.onclick = () => console.log('mySuperElement'); // Case 3: do not seems to work
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.style.display = 'block';

    let div = document.createElement('div');

    div.style.display = 'block';
    div.style.height = '50px';
    div.style.width = '50px';
    div.style["background-color"] = 'green';

    // div.onclick = () => console.log('myElementDiv'); // Case 4: Work but not exactly what I am looking for.

    this.appendChild(div);

    this.onclick = () => console.log('myElement'); // Case 2: do not seems to work
  }

  onclick() {
    console.log('mySuperElement'); // Case 1: do not seems to work
  }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement)
```

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```

Currently using Chrome 79.0.3945.88 for the fiddle if relevant.

Thanks

**Edits 1**
To provide some clarity.

I am extending HTMLElement `onclick` to define its behavior. But it does nothing. Why is that the case.

Seen in another way the `connectedCallback` function was extended properly and called when the dom element was attached, the `onclick` was not when the element is clicked. The `onclick` method on the extended class should binds itself to `this` just like connectedCallback.

From @ajuni880 comment, I understand that customElements might behave differently when extended than normal classes. Not quite sure if it makes sense yet.

Comment: you can check this https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements

Comment: @ajuni880 If I understand this properly, when using custom elements, the class itself is not an HTMLElement but a "custom element" and the "this" will represent the HTMLElement?

Comment: the `this` will represent the element because you are extending the base class `HTMLElement` and your custom element will have the properties of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to your created *div* and call your function with bind, like this:

```
connectedCallback() {
   ...
   div.addEventListener('click', this.myFunction.bind(this));

   this.appendChild(div);
}

myFunction() {
   console.log('my element');
}
```

Comment: This was done in my sample, but  as stated is not the usecase I wish for unless I get proven it can't be done otherwise.